# I'm looking for a way to keep a wire coiled when it's not being pulled on, and retract when it isn't

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm working on an application where a panel rests on a flat plane, and is hinged along one edge with a bit less than 90 degrees of travel. I need to run a wire from the flat plane to the edge of the panel opposite the hinges. What I'd like is to have a small spool of the wire located near where the target edge meets the plane. The spool should let out wire as the panel slowly rises, and as it slowly falls it should pull the wire back in.

What would a product that accomplishes this be called? [image: here's an image to describe the situation]

Comment: What is the function of this “wire”?

Comment: Why wouldn't a spring solve this problem?

Comment: Use a tape measure.

Answer (score 1):

Just bring the wire down to the hinge and have it go inline with the hinge so it rotates with the movement.

This is done on car tailgates and works fine. Some wires fail but only after several years...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a small spring loaded roller for window shade. They cost in the range of $20 and many hardware stores custom cut them down to something like 6 inches.

You can remove the shade and wind your wire around it.

here is a photo.

[image: spring loaded roller blind.]